# Callback on CSS animation end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, promise

I have a small jQuery function, where the return value must be fired in a subfunction. Reason: I want to chain this function later with other jQuery functions. But the next chained function should start after the main function returns the jQuery object

```
app.h.aniend = 'webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend';
$.fn.animate_scale = function( callback ) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('animate_scale').one( app.h.aniend, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animate_scale');
        if( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
            callback($this);
        }
        return $this; // return here...
    });
    // return $this;
};
```

Is there away to say jQuery to wait until subfunction returns the necessary jQuery objects for chaining?

```
$('#my_object').animate_scale().fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: That subfunction isn't being executed immediately though, it's waiting for the app.h.aniend event to be triggered, so no, the return value isn't known at the bottom of the outer function.

Comment: Why you don't want to use a callback `$('#my_object').animate_scale(function(){
        /* animate scale is done.*/
        $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    });`

Comment: You can also have a callback and even use exactly this code format: `$('#my_object').animate_scale().fadeOut(2000);` if you use `$.queue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $('#my_object').**animate_scale**().**fadeOut**(2000);

if you want `.fadeOut()` to wait for `animate_scale()` to finish, `animate_scale` needs to be queued:

### Queue your plugin:

Usually, when you **chain** [*fx* methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) like i.e:

```
$("#ball").animate({left:200}).fadeOut();
```

you'll see the ball animate, and only once that animation is finished --- it'll fade out.
**Why?** Cause jQuery will stach `animate` and than `fadeOut` into a `queue` array and wait each to resolve before triggering the next Method.

**To replicate the same behavior within your plugin:**

***[jsFiddle demo (Queue in action!)](http://jsfiddle.net/5sn8zocu/)***

```
$.fn.animate_scale = function( callback ) {
    var $this = this;
    return $this.queue(function() { 
        $this.addClass('animate_scale').on("animationend", function() {
            $this.dequeue();
            if (typeof callback == 'function') callback.call( $this );
        });
    });
};


$('#my_object').animate_scale(function() {
    console.log( "Scale is done!" );
}).fadeOut( 2000 ); // fadeOut will wait for animate_scale to dequeue (complete)
```

---

## I don't need queue stacking

If you want your plugin to unobstructively (simultaneously) process other chained *fx* Methods,
use just the callback:

***[jsFiddle demo (no Queue)](http://jsfiddle.net/5sn8zocu/1/)***

```
$.fn.animate_scale = function( callback ) {
  var $this = $(this);
  return $this.addClass('animate_scale').on("animationend", function() {
      if (typeof callback == 'function') callback.call( this );
  });
};

$('#my_object').animate_scale(function(){
    console.log("Scale done.");
                  // use $(this).fadeOut(2000); here!! cause otherwise...
}).fadeOut(2000); // ...if chained here, will fade immediately!!!!!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand the issue now better. I used for years the jQuery effects, but now i'm only uning CSS transforms, because on tablets and smartphone the animations are fluent (because of GPU-Usage) like web-browsers.

Comment: @AppGeer yes, CSS transitions and animations just rule. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a callback:

```
$('#my_object').animate_scale(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(2000) });
```

There's a really bad way of doing this which gives you exactly what you want, but again it's really bad:

```
app.h.aniend = 'webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend';
$.fn.animate_scale = function( callback ) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var fadeoutTime;
    $this.addClass('animate_scale').one( app.h.aniend, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animate_scale');
        if( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
            callback($this);
        }
        if(fadeoutTime) {
          $(this).fadeOut(fadeoutTime);
        }
    });
    return {
      fadeOut: function(time) { fadeoutTime = time; }
    };
};
```

and I repeat, this is OVERKILL because you can just use a callback and because you're limited to just `fadeOut`, but what it does is stores the value of the fadeOut call until you actually *want* to fadeout, and then it uses it. If you never fall `FadeOut` then `fadeoutTime` remains `undefined` and the fadeout doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a generalised method that :

- is not tied to a particular CSS3 selector
- will emulate jQuery's built-in animations such as `slideDown()` or `fadeIn()`.

If so, then the method (let's call it `.css3Animate()`) should work under *all* of the following circumstances :

```
// method-chain
$('#my_object').css3Animate('animate_scale').fadeOut(1000);
```

```
// callback
$('#my_object').css3Animate('animate_scale', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```
// .promise().then()
$('#my_object').css3Animate('animate_scale').promise().then(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

The following jQuery plugin anchieves these aims ...

```
(function($) {
    var aniend = 'webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend';
    $.fn.css3Anim = function(cssClass, callback) {
        var $this = this; // As we're in a plugin, `this` is already a jQuery collection.
        return this.queue(function(next) { // put the css animation in the elements' fx queue.
            $this.queue(function(){}) // block the animation queue while the CSS transition is in progress.
            .one(aniend, function() {
                if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback.call(this);
                }
                $this.removeClass(cssClass) // ready for another invocation
                .dequeue(); // allow the fx animation queue to progress, and resolve the associated promise.
            })
            .addClass(cssClass); // stimulate the required animation
            next(); // progress to the queue blocker above.
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sy51tyn5/1/

Behaviour is good but not perfect. The plugin is designed to allow two or more of these animations to be queued, but with only partial success. It appears to allow two but falls apart on three.

As you will see, in the demo the buttons are disabled while the animation is is progress. This prevents "meddling" while the CSS3 animation in underway. Try unchecking the checkbox and click away on the buttons; you will see that it's very easy to cause an upset.

Possibly this is because `next()` is not guaranteed to progress to the queue blocker - something else may intervene? More work needed to solve that one. Maybe someone clever can advise?

Comment: Running the same code for each of the three answers, [here are the results](http://jsfiddle.net/sy51tyn5/2/).